# Antipodal map is Smoothly homotopic to id

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Problem:

Fix $m\in \mathbb{N}$. Then antipodal map $\alpha: S^m \rightarrow S^m$ is defined by
$$S\in (x_1,x_2,...,x_{m+1})) \mapsto (-x_1,-x_2,...,-x_{m+1}).$$
Prove that the antipodal map  $\alpha: S^m \rightarrow S^m$ is smoothly homotopic to the identity map id:$S^m \rightarrow S^m$ whenever $m$ is odd.

### My Attempt

I still haven't quite been able to figure this out. I jotted down a few things I know and can't put them together...

- The antipodal map is a diffeomorphism of compact, connected manifolds.
- $S^{2n-1} \subset \mathbb{R}^{2n}$
- If $m$ is odd let $m=2k-1$. Consider $S^m$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^{2k}$. The coodinate pairs of $S^m$ is $(x_1,...,x_{2k})$ such that $\sum _{i=1}^n \vert x_i\vert ^2=1$ Define:

$$X:\mathbb{R}^{2k} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2k}$$ by
$$X((x_1,x_2,...,x_{2k-1},x_{2k})) = (-x_2,-x_1,...,-x_{2k},-x_{2k-1}).$$
Now,$X(v)$ is perpendicular to $v$ and $||X(v)||=1$ for all $v\in S^m$ so $X$ is a unit vector field

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let's consider the simplest case: $m = 1$.

- The identity map $(x_1, x_2) \mapsto (x_1, x_2)$ is a rotation through $0$ degrees.
- The antipodal map $(x_1, x_2 ) \mapsto (-x_1, -x_2)$ is a rotation through $180$ degrees.

How can we smoothly deform a $0$ degree rotation into a $180$ degree rotation?

Comment: trig functions?

Comment: You mean using trig functions to represent rotations? Yeah, that would work.

Comment: I am not sure how to answer your question

Comment: @combostudent: Remember what you want. You want a family of functions $f_{t}$ with smoothly transitions from the identity $f_{0}=\mathrm{id}$ to the antipodal map $f_{1}=\alpha.$ To do this, you'll need to come up with a parameter $t.$ What in this answer could be used as a parameter?

Comment: something that gets $X(v,0)=v$ and $X(v,1)=-v$ would work to get a homotopy

Comment: @combostudent  Can you think of a transformation that is "halfway" between a $0$ degree rotation and a $180$ degree rotation?

Comment: something to do with $\cos(\pi x) + \sin (\pi x)$ maybe? i am very stuck

Comment: Forget about equations for the time being. Try to visualise it. Do you understand intuitively what is a homotopy between two maps? How would you explain what a homotopy is to a non-mathematician?

Comment: @KennyWong we mean that if we have two sets $X$ and $Y$ and homotopy from $f$ to $g$ that sends elements from $X$ to $Y$ we mean there  is a continuous map from $X \times [0,1] \mapsto^H Y$ such that $h(x,0) =g(x)$ and $h(x,1)= g(x)$

Comment: And how would you say that in plain English?

Comment: Well, I've got to go now. I like to think of a homotopy between $f$ and $g$ as a _family_ of maps that continuously interpolate between $f$ and $g$. In your notation, you have a family of maps, $h_t(x)$, labelled by a parameter $t$. When $t = 0$, you have the map $h_0(x)$, which is $f(x)$. When $t = 1$, you have the map $h_1(x)$, which is $g(x)$. As $t$ increases from $0$ to $1$, the map $h_t(x)$ continuously deforms from $f(x)$ into $g(x)$.

Comment: @KennyWong after some research, the functions are being “continuously deformed” into the other, but i am not really sure what "deformed" is supposed to mean here

Comment: To give you an example, suppose $X = Y = \mathbb R$. Suppose $f(x) = x + 1$ and $g(x) = x + 2$. In plain English, $f$ is a translation by one unit, and $g$ is a translation by two units. A possible homotopy between $f$ and $g$ is defined by taking $h_t$ to be a translation by $1 + t$ units. Indeed, when $t = 0$, $h_t$ is a translation by one unit, and when $t = 1$, $h_t$ is a translation by two units, and when $t $ is in between $0$ and $1$, $h_t$ is a translation by an amount in between one and two units. So $h_t$ is a FAMILY of transformations of $X$, interpolating between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: To give you a second example, suppose $X = S^1$ and $Y = \mathbb R^2$. Suppose $f(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = (0,0)$ (i.e. $f$ contracts the circle to a point), and $g(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = (\cos \theta, \sin \theta)$ (i.e. $g$ maps the circle to a circle of unit radius in $\mathbb R^2$). Then a possible homotopy between $f$ and $g$ is given by $h_t(\cos \theta, \sin \theta) = (t \cos \theta, t \sin \theta)$. Indeed, when $t= 0$, $h_t = f$, and when $t = 1$, $h_t = g$. For $t$ in between $0$ and $1$, $h_t$ maps the $S^1$ to a circle of radius $t$ in $\mathbb R^2$....

Comment: ... so again, the $h_t$'s form a continuous family of mappings from $S^1$ to $\mathbb R^2$ that continuously interpolated between $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Now let's return to our question. We have $X = Y = S^1$. $f$ is a rotation of the $S^1$ through $0$ degrees. $g$ is a rotation of the $S^1$ through $180$ degrees. Once you have worked through the two other examples I've given you, and once you have visualised those examples, try to think of a way to continuously deform the $0$ degree rotation into a $180$ degree rotation. It's not a trick question at all. Just think of how you turn the steering wheel in a car!

Comment: Once you've visualised it, try to write down an expression for $h_t(x_1, x_2))$ that describes the family of transformations interpolating between $f$ and $g$. Your $h_t(x_1, x_2)$ should be continuous in $(x_1, x_2)$ and also continuous in $t$, with $h_0(x_1,x_2)) = f(x_1, x_2)$ and $h_1(x_1,x_2) = f(x_1, x_2)$. (In fact, for the purposes of this question, they should be smooth.) But it is very important that you visualise the mappings and the homotopies, and that you can describe the mappings and homotopies in words. Trying to guess equations with no visual intuition is hopelessly difficult.